# Precompiled windows binaries for pgRouting latest - v.2.4.1

Tags: pgrouting

I was trying to find precompiled windows 64-bit binaries of the latest [pgRouting release Version 2.4.1](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/releases/tag/v2.4.1) but all possible sources like

- http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/
- http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg96/

just list 2.3.2 as the highes available version. Is there any other approach than compiling the latest build on my windows machine?

For linux a precompiled version can be retrieved in form of the package `Postgresql-9.6-pgrouting`through ubuntugis-unstable. I am using the following source:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see pgRouting 2.4.1 in http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/

I haven't updated the pages though, I'll get to that later.
But they are in each folder for 9.4-9.6

e.g. 9.6 - http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg96/buildbot/

http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg96/buildbot/pgrouting-pg96-binaries-2.4.1w64gcc48.zip

I haven't released them yet as part of stackbuilder because I release with PostGIS.  So probably will release with PostGIS 2.3.3 in about a month or so.